# Setting an alarm based on date in database

Tags: java, android, date, calendar, android-alarms

I found a tutorial that helped me get a working alarm setup but in the tutorial we used a date picker to set the time of the alarm. All was going well, so I attempted to replace the date picker with a method of my own and set the alarm that way. Problem is it doesn't seem to be working, no alarm pops up when I set that date to today but works fine when I use the date picker. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I ran this through debug and my query is returning the proper date, I'm getting the right numbers and all but it doesn't seem to work.

I'm hoping someone can point out something I've missed?

**EDIT**

I call `setNotif()` through a button in the ui. I basically remodelled it to just have a button for testing. I get the toast but no alarm goes off no matter what I try.

**Here's the original date picker code**

```
public void onDateSelectedButtonClick(View v){

    int day = picker.getDayOfMonth();
    int month = picker.getMonth();
    int year = picker.getYear();

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(year, month, day);
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    scheduleClient.setAlarmForNotification(c);


    Toast.makeText(this, "Notification set for: "+ day +"/"+ (month+1) +"/"+ year, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**Here's the method I tried to replace it with**

It calls a query to get a specific date from my database and supposedly sets an alarm 3 days prior. I tested it by changing the date of my phone and by making it set the alarm to today as well but neither have worked.

```
public void setNotif() {

    // Getting the next date of payments which the alarm will be based on
    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    String thisdate = getCurDate();
    Cursor cur = db.nextdate(thisdate);
    String date= "";
    if (cur!= null) {
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            date = cur.getString(0);
        }
    }
    try {
        DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date input = inputFormat.parse(date);
        String finaldate = inputFormat.format(input);
        String d = finaldate.substring(8,10);
        String m = finaldate.substring(5,7);
        String y = finaldate.substring(0,4);
        int da = Integer.parseInt(d);
        int month = Integer.parseInt(m);
        int year = Integer.parseInt(y);
        int day = da - 3;

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(year, month, day);
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        scheduleClient.setAlarmForNotification(c);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Notification set for: "+ day +"/"+ month +"/"+ year, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }catch (Exception ex) {
        Alerts.CatchError(Kik.this, ex.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: where are you calling this method `setNotif()`?  Having it in the button callback forces the actions on the UI thread.  Is it possible you're in a background thread so the toast isn't toasting?

Comment: Oh forgot to mention that. I'll put it up in an edit, thanks.

Comment: What does the date look like in your database ? Are you sure it's inyyyy-MM-dd format ? Your method for converting to Calendar seems a little strange. Do you get anything in LogCat ?

Comment: I'm sorry it's my first time dealing with calendar and I just tried to supplement what I knew into the existing bits. Yeah I'm sure about the date, I've run it through debug mode and I get the expected date in the proper format and all. Also nothing on logcat, I get the `Toast` at the end but not alarm goes off ever.

Comment: I think you have a month problem.  The date picker returns a month that is 0 based.  In the toast in the example code it prints in the toast with a `month+1` so it looks right.  Your toast shows just month, so I bet your alarm is set a month off.

Comment: I also forgot to mention that, I've looked through SO for some stuff and I did come across that and did a lot of testing. I tried adding a month to it, setting the date to something I can't get wrong like 12-30-2015 and setting my system time to it but still nothing.

Comment: I think you want to subtract a month from it... so you want your month line to be something like: `int month = Integer.parseInt(m) - 1;`

Comment: Well that seems to have done it! Would you mind explaining why I needed to subtract my month though?

Comment: Yeah, I'll add an answer so I have some room to explain what's going on.

Comment: **Joda-Time**   This is just the beginning of the hurt and pain you'll suffer with use of java.util.Date and .Calendar classes. Avoid theses classes. Immediately add the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library and never look back. Works in Android. Search StackOverflow for "joda" to see many examples of usage.

Comment: If you're stuck using a version of java < 8, 100% agree with Joda-Time.  However, going forward Oracle/Java has made an attempt at fixing things / rewriting everything...  I'm not arguing against Joda-Time in Java 8, but know that date and time stuff is /supposed/ to be better in Java 8 (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an easy road block to run into, unfortunately and it doesn't *really* have anything to do with Android.  It's a holdover from Java date/calendar.

When you pull the date out of the `int month` out of the date picker in the example code the value you get out is 0 based:

```
int month = picker.getMonth();
// January -> 0
// February -> 1
// ...
// December -> 11
```

The dates in your database are dates we're used to looking at: `2016-12-25` is December 25th, 2016.

When you set the values for `Calendar` it is expecting a 0-indexed month.  You're giving it a 1-indexed month.  So you'll need to subtract 1 from the month to get the right value.  I'll make a table so it's clear what's going on:

```
Month String  |  Database Value  |  Calendar Value 
January       |  1               |  0
February      |  2               |  1
March         |  3               |  2
April         |  4               |  3
May           |  5               |  4
June          |  6               |  5
```

Hopefully that makes it obvious.

So in your case if you change the line:

```
c.set(year, month, day);
```

To be...

```
c.set(year, month - 1, day);
```

You'll win.

Comment: I see, so when using the `Calendar` adding 1 to the month is only for the purpose of representing a human date and is naturally the exact opposite for going from human date to a `Calendar` date. Thank you very much for that clarification. Cheers!